# Ubuntu 13.04 running within Hyper-V Networking very flaky

Tags: wireless, networking, windows-8, hyper-v

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 (I had started with 12.10) within Hyper-V (Windows 8 Pro) on a Samsung series 9 laptop. I have the wireless and wired interfaces shared with the VM.

I've been noticing that the wireless connectivity (i.e. network connectivity within the VM when the host is connected over wifi) is extremely flaky. Typically in some scenarios the connection fails to get established.

In other scenarios, the guest get an IP address and is able to connect while the host (windows) doesn't pick up an IP address. So I have this weird scenario where the guest can get to the internet but not the host.

Any hints/ tips /suggestions. Let me know if there's any diagnostic information that might help.

Note this is a sporadic failure (about 20-30% of the time)

Answer (score 1):

I googled some more and found the answer here https://superuser.com/questions/489746/ubuntu-not-connecting-to-network-in-hyper-v. Note even without this the connectivity was working sporadically. I'll post back in a few days if it crops up. If you don't hear back from me it a sign that its working :)